# Route optimization software

Tags: optimization

What will be the best software recommendation for route optimization. Which includes the following vehicles and Jobs constraints.

**For Vehicles:-** Each vehicle will have the following parameters

- **Load Capacity:-** Max load capacity of the vehicle.
- **Availability Time Slot:-** Time window in which this particular vehicle is available for use.
- **Start & End Points:-** Locations at which the truck will start and end its trip.

**For JOBS:-**

- Each Job has some volume.
- Each Job has some service time that is required to do the job once it reaches its destination.
- Each Job has to be completed with a given time-window which can be different for each job.
- Each Job belongs to one of the 4 categories which are as follows :-

  - **Delivery**:- Something is loaded in the vehicle at the warehouse before the trip starts and then it delivers it somewhere before returning back.
  - **Pickup**:- During the trip, vehicle can pick up one or more things which are to be brought back to the warehouse.
  - **Pickup+Delivery**:- Here the vehicle will pick up something during the trip after leaving the warehouse and will deliver the same to some location before returning back. Here Nothing will be loaded at or brought back to the warehouse.
  - **Delivery+Pickup**:- Here the vehicle will deliver something at a location that was loaded into it before the trip started and will pick up some other things from the same location that will be brought back to the warehouse.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [OptaPlanner](https://www.optaplanner.org/learn/useCases/vehicleRoutingProblem.html): the VRP example supports CVRP, VRPTW, etc. The optaweb-vehicle-routing web application integrates OpenStreetMaps and provides a nice webui.